# How to find basis for an image of a subset under a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was watching the [khan acadamey videos on linear algebra](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix_transformations/linear_transformations/v/image-of-a-subset-under-a-transformation).

Sal shows that the transformation $T$ of a subspace $S$ is another subspace $T(S)$. Since $S$ and $T(S)$ can have different dimensions, how do I find the basis for $T(S)$ if know the matrix $\mathbf A$ such that $T(\mathbf x) = \mathbf A\mathbf x$ and I know the basis for $S$?

For example if $S$ is a line in $\mathbb R^2$, and $T:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$; does the transformation of the basis of $S$ form a basis of $T(S)$? Is it possible $T(S)$ be a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ or must it be a line or a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a basis of the image of a linear transformation $T(\vec{x})=A\vec{x}$, you first find a generating set, then remove elements until you have a basis.

A generic set is given by the columns of $A$. To remove redundant columns, you need to know which columns are linear combinations of other columns. This you can do by doing row operations on $A$ and reducing to *[reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)* $A_{red}$. The columns in the reduced matrix $A_{red}$ having a pivot element correspond to the columns in $A$ that are part of a basis.

Comment: Wait, I can find the basis from the columns of A? Does this mean I can think of T (and thus A) as a change-of-basis (with some possible redundancy)?

Comment: First question: yes. A subset of the columns of $A$ is a basis for the image of $T$. (I guess you could think of $T$ as a "change of space"-thingy, but I don't know how standard that would be)

Comment: Hold the phone: A subset of the columns of A is a basis for the image of T, not for the image of S under T.

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff Yes, that is correct. But you can always express find a basis $\{s_1,\cdots, s_n \}$ for $S$. Then  a subset of the image of the basis $\{Ts_1,\cdots, Ts_n\}$ is a basis of the image of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Always $dim(T(S))\le dim(S)$, so the answer for the question in the example is a line through the origin or the origin (both are subspaces).
 To form a basis for $T(S)$ form a matrix $V$ w/columns consisting of the basis vectors for $S$, then find the largest square submatrix w/non-zero determinant in the product matrix $AV$, the corresponding column vectors form a basis for $T(S)$.
 SVD decomposition of $A$ may give an alternative algorithm.

Comment: Glad to see my intuition is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Denote $X_S$ to be a basis of $S$. You aren't guaranteed $T(X_S)$ to be a basis of $T(S)$, just by a counting argument: Suppose $T: U \to V$ is a linear transformation, and dim $U = 3$ but dim $V = 2$, then $T(X_U)$ can have at most 2 linearly dependent elements. If dim $U = 2$, dim $V = 3$, there is no way that $T(X_U)$ can span $V$.

Now, since $T$ is always (just from the definition) onto its image $T(S)$, we will know that $T(X_S)$ is a basis if $T$ is injective i.e. preserves linear independence of vectors. This happens when $A$ has a trivial null space, if you follow the definitions through.